# Hadoop Mapreduce: How to partition data from mapper to reducer

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, streaming

I have tested map.py and reduce.py in the local environment.

The input file like:

```
R55726rest149624640000014962753030007006483323902288110000NJ110112hoboken   R55726rest149636308400014964192000007063481824780452130000NY130800hoboken   R23412rest149641920000014965055650007063480924780416130000NJ130800weehawken
```

The output of Map like:

```
R55726,1496246400000,1496275303000,70064833,23902288,Hoboken
R55726,1496289016000,1496293537000,70685312,24637310,Hoboken
R12345,1496357338000,1496357862000,70634437,24780843,Jersey city
R12345,1496357921000,1496361659000,70632989,24780983,Jersey city
```

Then I want to partition the output data of Map by the first column.

Final output will have two files:part-00000, part-00001

The run.sh:

```
-D stream.map.output.field.separator=, \
-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=2 \
-D map.output.key.field.separator=, \
-D num.key.fields.for.partition=1 \
-numReduceTasks 1 \
```

But it dosen't work.
Chould you tell me how to modify the program? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Hadoop docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-streaming/HadoopStreaming.html#Hadoop_Partitioner_Class) :

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar \
  -D stream.map.output.field.separator=. \
  -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=4 \
  -D map.output.key.field.separator=. \
  -D mapreduce.partition.keypartitioner.options=-k1,2 \
  -D mapreduce.job.reduces=12 \
  -input myInputDirs \
  -output myOutputDir \
  -mapper /bin/cat \
  -reducer /bin/cat \
  -partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner
```

The property you are looking for is `mapreduce.partition.keypartitioner.options`.

You also need to specify your partitioner. In your case, one of the defaults, `KeyFieldBasedPartitioner` would work.

Comment: I modify the docs, but it stills doesn't work. But I use and modify another run.sh,  it works. I don't know why, but thank you for your answer.